# Calling Java class/method using command line

Tags: java, command-line

I want to write a Java program so that I can call it using the command-line, something like

> java hearts/NewDeck | java hearts/Shuffle

which involves passing the output of the first command as the input of the second command. How should I structure the program? Should NewDeck/Shuffle be classes or methods?

Comment: There are no functions in java. Please read [at least one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/newtojava/downloads/index.html) tutorial about the language, this is **extremely** basic stuff you're asking. This site is for specific programming problems.

Comment: java always wants to call the method called [`main`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN) when run from the command-line.  There can only be one [`main`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN) per class, so you may like to create two separate classes so you can have two separate `main` methods.  Another way of doing things is to have one `main` method and pass [arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html), then use conditional logic to do different things based on the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Each of them is a Java program like all the others, it is not the JVM who controls from where the input comes but the OS that does.

Just both of them as normal Java programs (`main` method), no special needs here.